# Coding theory - Syndromes error

Tags: linear-algebra, coding-theory

> Determine the dual code $C ^\perp$ to the code C given by following generating matrix $G$
>
> \begin{bmatrix}
>     0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
>     0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
>     1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1
>    \end{bmatrix}
>
> And determinate the coset leaders and syndromes. If $y = 01001$ is received, which word from $C^ \perp$ is most likely to have been transmitted?

**What I've done so far:**

$C ^\perp=<10010,11101>. $ Because we have $(C ^\perp)^\perp=C$, it means that the parity-check matrix of $C ^\perp$ is $G$.
So I can calculate the syndromes and leaders with $S(y)=Gy^T$.

Let $e_1=(10000)$, $e_2=(01000)$, $\cdot \cdot \cdot , e_5=(00001)$

So we have

\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
Syndromes & Coset\ leaders  \\ \hline
 000&0 \\ \hline
 001&e_1=e_4 \\ \hline
 100&e_2 \\ \hline
010&e_3 \\ \hline
111&e_5 \\ \hline
110&e_2+e_3 \\ \hline
011&e_1+e_3=e_4+e_3 \\ \hline
101&e_1+e_2=e_4+e_2 \\ \hline
\end{array}

We know $y = c + e$, where $c$ is the codeword transmitted, and $e$ is
the error vector.
$eH^T = (y - c)H^T = yH^T - cH^T = yH^T - 0 = yH^T$

Calculating we get: $yH^T=(011)$

But $(011)$ can be from $e_1+e_3$ or $e_4+e_3$.

What do I do now?

If I choose $e_1+e_3$, then $c=01001-10100=11100$, if I choose  $e_4+e_3$ , then $c=01001-00110=01111$.

Whats the real answer?

Comment: Pick either $e_1+e_3$ or $e_4+e_3$. You could use $e_2+e_5$ even.

Comment: @MathLover If I choose $e_1+e_3$ I get a different result if I choose $e_4+e_3$..

Comment: The minimum distance of the code is $2$. Therefore, you cannot correct even single bit errors. You are trying to correct two bit errors! For error correction, you pick any of $e_1+e_3$, $e_3+e_4$, and $e_2+e_5$ as the error pattern and perform error correction. That is, you output $11100$, $01111$, or $00000$.

Comment: @MathLover A code $C$ with minimum distance $d$ detects $d-1$ errors, and only corrects $ \lfloor{ \frac{d-1}{2}} \rfloor$ errors , right?